# VBA Files fail to open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Roll up file that opens multiple excel workbooks and copies data from them into a master file. The program has been running fine for months but for the last few days its been failing when opening some files. i get the following error message.

Run-Time Error '1004':

Excel Cannot open the file "filename.xlsm" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

If I hit debug and continue running the program the file then opens without a problem.  If I restart the program it will still fail to open files but its never the same files.  I cant find any problems with the workbooks that fail when I go into them and the file extensions are correct.  I have error handling to check if any one is currently in the workbook too, so I don't think that can be it.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

```
    If Not FileLocked(CStr(FoundFiles(iIndex))) Then
    On Error GoTo contentErr
    Workbooks.Open FoundFiles(iIndex) ', UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Run ("'Auto Update Roll-Up.xlsm'!Update")
    With Workbooks(tempvar(iIndex - 1))
        .Close False
        LogInformation ("Completed " & tempvar(iIndex - 1) & " at " & Now)
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
        '.Close True
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End If
Continue:
Next iIndex
On Error Resume Next
DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("Brickman Roll-Up Template.xlsm").Close savechanges:=True
'Workbooks("Brickman Roll-Up Template Test.xlsm").Close savechanges:=True
SetAttr rollupPath, vbReadOnly
Workbooks("Auto Update Roll-Up.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False
DisplayAlerts = True
LogInformation ("Program ended at " & Now)
Application.Quit

contentErr:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    LogInformation ("_______There is unreadable content in " & Chr(34) & tempvar(iIndex        - 1) & Chr(34) & "_______")
    GoTo Continue
End If
End Sub



Function FileLocked(strFileName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
' If the file is already opened by another process,
' and the specified type of access is not allowed,
' the Open operation fails and an error occurs.
Open strFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
Close #1
' If an error occurs, the document is currently open.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ' Display the error number and description.
  LogInformation ("Couldn't open " & strFileName & " because it is already checked   out.")
  FileLocked = True
  Err.Clear
End If
End Function
```

the error occurs on the line  Workbooks.Open FoundFiles(iIndex)

Comment: what is `FoundFiles` then? in that function is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur when you give the workbook a defined name and then copy the worksheet several times without first saving and closing the workbook, as in the following sample code:

```
Sub CopySheetTest()
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim oBook As Workbook
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    ' Create a new blank workbook:
    iTemp = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iTemp

    ' Add a defined name to the workbook
    ' that RefersTo a range:
    oBook.Names.Add Name:="tempRange", _
        RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1"

    ' Save the workbook:
    oBook.SaveAs "c:\test2.xls"

    ' Copy the sheet in a loop. Eventually,
    ' you get error 1004: Copy Method of
    ' Worksheet class failed.
    For iCounter = 1 To 275
        oBook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=oBook.Worksheets(1)        
    Next
End Sub
```

To resolve this problem, save and close the workbook periodically while the copy process is occurring, as in the following sample code:

> Sub CopySheetTest()
>       Dim iTemp As Integer
>       Dim oBook As Workbook
>       Dim iCounter As Integer
>
> ```
> ' Create a new blank workbook:
> iTemp = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
> Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
> Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
> Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iTemp
>
> ' Add a defined name to the workbook
> ' that RefersTo a range:
> oBook.Names.Add Name:="tempRange", _
>     RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1"
>
> ' Save the workbook:
> oBook.SaveAs "c:\test2.xls"
>
> ' Copy the sheet in a loop. Eventually,
> ' you get error 1004: Copy Method of
> ' Worksheet class failed.
> For iCounter = 1 To 275
>     oBook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=oBook.Worksheets(1)
>     'Uncomment this code for the workaround:
>     'Save, close, and reopen after every 100 iterations:
>     If iCounter Mod 100 = 0 Then
>         oBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
>         Set oBook = Nothing
>         Set oBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("c:\test2.xls")
>     End If
> Next End Sub
> ```

Source - "MSDN"

Comment: I don't think this applies to my situation the error I'm getting in opening the workbook not in copying a work book. ill add some code to my original post

Answer (score 0):

You may get better help if you clarify and/or post more code. Specifically: 1) Are you getting the error on the `Workbooks.Open` in your main routine, or on the `Open` in your `FileLocked` function? 2) What is the relationship between `FoundFiles()` (which you use to Open) and `tempvar()` (which you use to Close)? How are you setting these arrays/variables?

Without that info, here's my best suggestion: use a Workbook variable in your `iIndex` loop. So, before your loop add

```
Dim wbLoop as Workbook
```

Then instead of

```
Workbooks.Open FoundFiles(iIndex)
```

use

```
Set wbLoop = Workbooks.Open(FoundFiles(iIndex))
```

and instead of

```
With Workbooks(tempvar(iIndex - 1))
```

use

```
With wbLoop
```

And before closing your If block, add

```
Set wbLoop = Nothing
```

Comment: the line the error is occurring at is Workbooks.Open FoundFiles(iIndex), tempvar is = to FoundFiles(iIndexs) i don't know why this was done this way i didn't write this code, seams totally unnecessary to me. I've got solved now any way though. my pings on the server the files are hosted on are occasionally timing out. I think its most likely the server isn't responding quick enough when the program tries to open a file on it.